# Django-sitegate, not sure where to set settings mentioned in documentation

Tags: django

I am trying to install and configure django-sitegate as a simple user registration form, as it fits my requirements perfectly.

In the [documentation](http://django-sitegate.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html), it mentions:

> Add the sitegate application to INSTALLED_APPS in your settings file
>   (usually ‘settings.py’). Make sure TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS in your
>   settings file has django.core.context_processors.request. For Django
>   1.8+: django.template.context_processors.request should be defined in TEMPLATES/OPTIONS/context_processors.

I added sitegate to my installed apps, but I am unsure where to how to set TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS as this variable is not already in any of my settings files (searched with recursive grep), and I can't find an example on how to set it.

As I am on django 1.1.13, the part about defining django.template.context_processors.request would apply to me, but I also can't find anythong on how to do that. The file at TEMPLATES/OPTIONS/context_processors does not exist, and other files I found called context_processors were all different from each other and overwhelming.

How can I find more information to explain the staps in the sitegate documentation more clearly, or what would be the best way to approach this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in Django 1.8+ they made breaking changes to the way template settings interact with Django. What the documentation means is that you should ensure you have included the `'django.template.context_processors.request'` value to the `TEMPLATES/OPTIONS/context_processors` setting in your projects `settings.py` file .

Here's some example code

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
         'context_processors': [
              ....
              'django.template.context_processors.request',
              ..... 
        ],
        # ... some options here ...
    },
},
```

]

here's the link to the relevant documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/templates/#configuration